# Law of Partitions - Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I need a bit of help with the completion of this proof for the following proposition (Prop 2.8, A Course In Probability, Neil A. Weiss):

Suppose that $A_1, A_2, \dots A_n$ form a partition of the sample space $\Omega$.

Then, for each event $B$, 
$P(B) = \sum\limits_{n}P(A_n \cap B)$.

The intended proof for this question is to do it by mathematical induction. My step process is as follows:

**Base Case/Anchor** ($n=1$.) i.e., there is 1 partition $A_1$ of $\Omega$ where $A_1 = \Omega$. Thus, $P(A_1 \cap B) = P(\Omega \cap B) = P(B)$ since $(B \subset \Omega)$.

Inductive Hypothesis. ($n=k, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq 1$).
Assume that for $k$ partitions that $P(B) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} P(A_n \cap B)$.

**Inductive Step** (Need to show the statement holds true for $n=k+1$).

This is the part of the proof where I am having trouble.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k+1}P(A_n \cap B) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}P(A_n \cap B) + P(A_{k+1} \cap B) = P(B) + P(A_{k+1} \cap B)$, which I am not sure if this is correct.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it you who wants to prove it by induction, or is it said to do so?

Comment: It is said to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Here's an alternative that is arguably better. Let $A_1,...,A_k,A_{k+1}$ be a partition of $\Omega.$ Put $C_j=A_j$ for $1\le j<k$ and put $C_k=A_k\cup A_{k+1}.$ Then $C_1,...,C_k$ is a partition of $\Omega,$ and by inductive hypothesis $$\begin{align}P(B) &= \sum_{j=1}^k P(B\cap C_k)\\ &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}P(B\cap A_j)\right)+P\bigl(B\cap(A_k\cup A_{k+1})\bigr)\\ &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}P(B\cap A_j)\right)+P\bigl((B\cap A_k)\cup(B\cap A_{k+1})\bigr).\end{align}$$ Can you take it the rest of the way? (**Hint**: Do $B\cap A_k$ and $B\cap A_{k+1}$ overlap at all?)

Answer (score 1):

In the last displayed equation, you have used 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_{k} \cap B) = P(B)$$
but that is not justified, because the $A_1$, …, $A_n$ do not necessarily form a partition of $\Omega$. Remember, your assumption is that $A_1$, …, $A_n$, $A_{n+1}$ partition $\Omega$.

Maybe you can finesse things to get a partition of size $n$ instead of $n+1$?

Edit: Looks like you're also mixing up the $k$'s and the $n$'s. Typically the convention is to induct on $n$ and use $k$ an an index. People will have a lot easier time following you if you do it that way.

You want to use "If $A_1$, … $A_n$ form a partition of $\Omega$ then $P(B) = \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k \cap B)$" to prove "If $A_1$, … $A_n$, $A_{n+1}$ form a partition of $\Omega$ then $P(B) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} P(A_k \cap B)$" Note that the $A_{i}$ in the second statement are NOT the same as the $A_i$ in the first. They're just symbols for any partition of that size.

Comment: Thank you TBrendle. I understand the flaw in my argument up to that point. But, how would I be able to convert a partition of size $n+1$ to one of size $n$? Would that involve adding a partition to size $n$ to get $n+1$ or the opposite, where I remove a partition from $n+1$ to get $n$?

Comment: hint: if $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, …, $A_{n+1}$ partition $\Omega$, then  show that $A_1 \cup A_2$, $A_3$, …, $A_{n+1}$ is a partition of $\Omega$ as well. You've just glued two of them together and so now instead of a partition of size $n+1$ you have a partition of size $n$, which you know by hypothesis satisfies the equation.